# R: attempt to webscrape using unlist(xpathSApply( )) results in NULL

Tags: r, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am working with the following website: http://www.crowdrise.com/skollsechallenge

Specifically on this page there are 57 crowdfunding campaigns.  Each of those crowdfunding campaigns have text that details out why they want to raise money, the total money raised so far, and the team members.  Some of the campaigns also specify the fundraising goal. I want to write some R code that will scrape and organize this information from each of the 57 sites.

In order to come up with a table that includes all these information for each of the 57 companies, I first generated function that would allow me to extract name of each of the 57 campaigns:

```
  #import packages
  library("RCurl")
  library("XML")
  library("stringr")

  url <- "http://www.crowdrise.com/skollSEchallenge"
  url.data <- readLines(url) 
  #the resulting url.data is a character string
  #remove spaces
  url.data <- gsub('\r','', gsub('\t','', gsub('\n','', url.data)))  
  index.list <- grep("username:",url.data)
  #index.list is a list of integers that indicates indexes of url.data that includes name      
  #of each of the 57 campaigns  
  length.index.list<-length(index.list)
  length.index.list
  vec <-vector ()

  #store the 57 usernames in one vector
    for(i in 1:length.index.list){
      username<-url.data[index.list[i]]
      real.username <- gsub("username:","",username)
      vec[i] <- c(real.username)
    }
```

and then I tried to make a loop to allow R to access each of the 57 campaign web pages, and do the webscraping .

```
 # Extract all necessary paragraphs. Unlist flattens the list to 
 #create a character vector.

    for(i in 1:length(vec)){
    end.name<-gsub('\'','',vec[i])
    end.name<-gsub(',','',end.name)
    end.name<-gsub(' ','',end.name)
    user.address<-paste(c("http://www.crowdrise.com/skollSEchallenge/",
    end.name),collapse='') 
    user.url<-getURL(user.address)

    html <- htmlTreeParse(user.url, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
    website.donor<-unlist(xpathSApply(html,'//div[@class="grid1-4 "]//h4', xmlValue))
    website.title<-unlist(xpathSApply(html,'//div[@class="project_info"]',xmlValue))
    website.story<-unlist(xpathSApply(html,'//div[@id="thestory"]',xmlValue))
    website.fund<-unlist(xpathSApply(html,'//div[@class="clearfix"]',xmlValue))

    #(NOTE: doc.text<- readHTMLTable(webpage1) doesn't work 
    #due to the poor html structure of the website)
    # Replace all \n by spaces, and eliminate all \t
    website.donor <- gsub('\\n', ' ', website.donor)
    website.donor <- gsub('\\t','',website.donor)
    website.title <- gsub('\\n', ' ', website.title)
    website.title <- gsub('\\t','',website.title)
    website.story <- gsub('\\n', ' ', website.story)
    website.story <- gsub('\\t','',website.story)
    website.fund <- gsub('\\n', ' ', website.fund)
    website.fund <- gsub('\\t','',website.fund)

    ## all those tabs and spaces are just white spaces that we can trim
    website.title <- str_trim(website.title)
    website.fund   <- str_trim(website.fund)
    website.data<- cbind(website.title, website.story, website.fund, website.donor)
    data[[i]]<- website.data
    Sys.sleep(1)
   }
  data <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,data), stringAsFactors=F)
```

the commands

```
   unlist(xpathSApply(html,'//div[@class="grid1-4 "]//h4', xmlValue))
   unlist(xpathSApply(html,'//div[@class="project_info"]',xmlValue))
   unlist(xpathSApply(html,'//div[@id="thestory"]',xmlValue))
   unlist(xpathSApply(html,'//div[@class="clearfix"]',xmlValue))
```

are giving me NULL value, and I do not understand why.

Why are they turning out to be NULL, and how can I fix it?

thank you,

Comment: At a first guess, if the xpath query doesn't match anything for xpathSApply (which probably shouldn't be wrapped in unlist but that's not the issue) then it will return an empty list. But more broadly I'd say you should refactor the question to ask a specific R/XML related Q, it's pretty narrow right now and more related to how you wrote the scraper than something that could be of general use.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following this correctly, you are trying to get this url string and 56 others?

```
url <- "http://www.crowdrise.com/skollSEchallenge/Arzu"
x <- getURL(url)
```

However, that just returns the "Page Not Found" page, which you are trying to query. I think you want this url, but I can't even get htmlParse to work.

```
url <- "http://www.crowdrise.com/Arzu"
x <- readLines(url, encoding="latin1")
 #doc <- htmlParse(x)  # hangs
```

If you check the site using http://validator.w3.org and the latin1 encoding, you'll find 323 errors, so you may need to parse the output from readLines

```
x[grep('"thestory"', x)+1]
[1] "\t\t\t<p><p><em><strong>&quot;We can overcome misunderstanding by ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you're interested in Crowdrise.  We offer an API that would probably work a whole lot better than automated scraping of our website. Use our contact form to get in touch or message me directly and we'll discuss what your needs are and how we can help you.

Thanks!

Dave